# Android EditText with animated hint?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I create an Android EditText with a hint like this (with animation)?

[image]

So when I tap inside the EditText, the hint shrinks and goes on top of the input text, like in this example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the code given below for all purposes:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/label">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

For Password filed with toggle eye use this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
...
app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    ...
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Learn more from here: https://material.io/components/text-fields/android